# I am trying to print a list,which will have all the values which occurred more than once in the source list ,complexity should be as less as possible

Tags: python-3.x, data-structures

I am trying to print a list, which will have all the values which occurred more than once in the source list, below is the solution I have used but it have time complexity of O(n*n), can somebody help me to print same result with less time complexity.

```
arr = [1,7,0,2,2,1,3,2,6,7]
req_arr = []
arrlen = len(arr)

for i in range(arrlen):
  for j in range(i+1,arrlen):
    if arr[i] == arr[j]:
      if arr[i] in req_arr:
        continue
      else :
        req_arr.append(arr[i])

print(req_arr) 

#output : [1, 7, 2]
#time complexity : O(n*n)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an O(2n) solution. We have two **separate** for-loops

```
arr = [1,7,0,2,2,1,3,2,6,7]

count = dict.fromkeys(arr,0)# initializing to zero
for i in arr:
    count[i] += 1

[i for i,j in count.items() if j>1]
[1, 7, 2]
```

Comment: The textbook answer would be very similar to this, but using a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter): `[i for i, j in Counter(arr).items() if j > 1]`

Answer (score 0):

I tried this:

```
c = []
for i in a:
    if i not in c:
        if a.count(i) >1:
            c.append(i)

print(c)
```

for the given list it took `4.0531158447265625e-06` time

Comment: This still has a time complexity of O(n^2) since you are doing `count`